# AWS : Python Script to Retrieve list of S3 bucket having Cross account access using boto3

Tags: python, python-3.x, bash, amazon-web-services, boto3

Is there any way we can check which bucket having cross account access using boto3? if not please suggest other way to do the same(using script only).

i am having multiple aws account.
ex: prod, dev, QA, rep1 etc...
i am using loop to go each and every account and creating the list of buckets those having cross account access.

Comment: Could you please clarify your requirements? Are you wanting to know what buckets in other accounts you have access to, or are you asking which of your existing buckets can be accessed by other accounts? If you provide more information, you will likely receive a better answer.

Comment: Thanks @JohnRotenstein. I want to know the which of my existing bucket can be accessed by other accounts.

Answer (score 1):

That's a hard question to answer, because a bucket might be accessible to one account or multiple accounts. It really comes down to the contents of your Bucket Policy on each bucket.

If you have [blocked public access](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/amazon-s3-block-public-access-another-layer-of-protection-for-your-accounts-and-buckets/) then a bucket is only accessible to another account if the Bucket Policy permits it.

It looks like the [IAM Policy Simulator](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_policies_testing-policies.html) (which also has an API) does not support cross-account testing, so that's apparently not an option.

Your only choice would be to parse each Bucket Policy to determine what access is being provided.

Also, you will also want to decide what you mean by "having access". Normally, `GetObject` is the test for being able to download objects, but a policy might also grant permission to list the content of a bucket, upload to the bucket, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks John
I have created below script to check bucket having cross account access or not on the basis of bucket policy.  But not sure weather this is sufficient or need to do more validation in script

```
import boto3
import json

REGIONS = 'ap-south-1'
ACCOUNT = '*************'
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = '*******************'
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = '*****************************'
client = boto3.client('s3', REGIONS, aws_access_key_id=AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, aws_secret_access_key=AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY)
flag = "cross account access -- no"
try:
    result = client.get_bucket_policy(Bucket='testingcrossaccount')
    policy = json.loads(result['Policy'])
    statements = policy['Statement']
    for statement in statements:
        effect = statement['Effect']
        principal = statement['Principal']
        try:
            keywords = principal['AWS']
            if isinstance(keywords, str):
                keywordarr = keywords.split(":")
                if (ACCOUNT != keywordarr[4] and effect == "Allow"):
                    flag = "cross account access -- yes"
            elif isinstance(keywords, list):
                for key in keywords:
                    keywordarr = key.split(":")
                    if (ACCOUNT != keywordarr[4] and effect == "Allow"):
                        flag = "cross account access -- yes"
                        break                   
            if (flag == "cross account access -- yes"):
                break
        except:
            if (principal == "*" and effect == "Allow"):
                flag = "cross account access -- yes"
 except:
    flag = "cross account access -- no"

print (flag)
```